# How to create CSS shape with full screen size

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a shape like attached below using css in full width screen, but not able to achieve, Here is the example image

[image: down arrow shape]

This is what I have tried so far (but wanted to make it responsive)

```css
 body
{
background:#090d15; 
}
.arrow-shape{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 55px 190px 0 190px;
border-color: #082947 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it with vw and vh if it can be fullscreen.

```css
.arrow-shape{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 20vh 50vw 0 50vw;
border-color: #082947 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-shape"></div>
```

Comment: great, I wasn't sure if I could use `vw` in border-width. thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Sure. No Problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you combine viewport units and `px`, it will scale to full width and have its height kept at `55px`

```css
body
{
margin: 0;
background:#090d15; 
}
.arrow-shape{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 55px 50vw 0 50vw;
border-color: #082947 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="100%"
  viewBox="0 0 60 50" height="50px" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polyline points="0,0 0,10 30,50 60,10 60,0"
    stroke-width="0" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a full-page, you can use the ``vh`and`vw` properties for your border.

100vw means 100% of the viewport width. I'll let you guess for vh !